# Looking for tsp RPM/package for RHEL 7

Tags: linux, rhel

I am looking for tsp "task-spooler" rpm for RHEL 7..

Can anyone help please?
Note: I do not have registration with RHEL.

Thanks
Yamen

Comment: Your best chance is to grab the source RPM or just the tarball and build the RPM yourself using `mock` tool.

Answer (score 0):

You can find it in Fedora project. Here is the [link](https://fedora.pkgs.org/37/fedora-x86_64/task-spooler-1.0.2-2.fc37.x86_64.rpm.html) to (probably) last version.

Comment: This most probably isn't compatible and is build against a different glibc version. This isn't going to work on RHEL systems since RHEL tends to be conservative in that matter

Comment: @ValentinBajrami, there is such probability. But we can't help much as OP do not have RHEL subscription and try to build something with nothing.